# Why does my 'transform' not work?

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

```css
.rotate {
  display: block;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border: 2px black dashed;
  animation: rotate 40s linear infinite;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(1.8);
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate"></div>
```

if you take a look at the fiddle, the "transform: scale(1.8);" didn't work. Is there any other alternatives to make the border bigger?

Comment: Why don't you just...increase the border-width?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? If you want a thicker border, just increase it from 2px.

Comment: i want it to look this big https://jsfiddle.net/frn6mqrg/2/ with the rotating animation.

Comment: It works in the snippet runner!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go. The transform isn't working when you're trying to scale in the initial rotate class is because, its gradually changing because of the rotating animation. You have to fix/scale the width or height initially and your border size then apply the animation on it as shown.

```css
.rotate {
 display: block;
 width: 115px;
 height: 115px;
 border: 4px black dashed;
 animation: rotate 40s linear infinite;
 border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    } 
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate"></div>
```

Comment: i see. another question, how do i increase the gap between the border?

Comment: What do you mean by the gap? Do you mean the white space between each border block?

Comment: That would be a different question. I recommend you make a separate question for it. @FreakS I think you need border-image for that, however.

Comment: @Maharkus Yep, you do need border-image for that. Since, the border-style is rendered differently by different browsers, there is no way to actually manipulate enough other than its color and thickness.

Comment: You could also make an SVG, which will allow you to actually change the color of the border, should that be neccessary

Answer (score 0):

Not that hard really. Increase the height and width manually and increase the border-width.

```css
.rotate {
  display: block;
  width: 115px;
  height: 115px;
  border: 4px black dashed;
  animation: rotate 40s linear infinite;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate"></div>
```

Comment: Lol , I posted the same answer before and got it rated down? lol